# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with nested elements

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

### Problem

[image]

I would like to show a list of elements but those elements are nested inside groups ("playlist" in the example). The data of the elements to show are instead in another node ("movies" in the example).

I tried with 2 different approaches but nothging works:

(1) **With FirebaseRecyclerAdapter**

In *FirebaseRecyclerAdapter* I can pass only a databasereference and in that case would be *getReference(MoviePlayLists).child(User-Id-1)* and it doesn't work.

I tried to create my custom model class on those nodes and override in the adapter *parseSnapshot()* but I cannot populate the View correctly in *populateView()* because it is called on "MoviePlayLists" nodes and not sub-nodes.

(2) **With FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter**

Because the reference for keys is again nested I'm not able to use it.

---

**Do you have any idea on the correct approach to do it with this DB structure? Is it possible?**

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the correct way of doing it but here is how I would implement it

```
Query keyref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User-Id");
Query dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User-Id");
```

now create a class extending FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter
and attach it to the recyclerView.

now int the populateViewHolder() method fetch the movie-id details

```
populateViewHolder(final VIEW_HOLDER vh, final String movie_id, final int position){

 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(movie_id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Movie m = dataSnapshot.getValue(MODEL_CLASS_FOR_MOVIE_ID);

           // update you movie details here

        }
    });
}
```

If anyone has a better solution please comment!

Comment: Hi, is it correct to pass the same database reference to keyRef and dRef? Or it is an error?

Attaching the "User-ID" I have the impression that I will find only 3 nodes (PlayLists)

Comment: keyref would get the keys at the node "User-Id" {PlayList-1, PlayList-2} and query the dref using the retrieved key i.e at "User-Id"/PlayList-1 which would get the required value {Movie-ID-1, Movie-ID-2}.